# how to evaluate script tag with some javascript in json responce in angular

Tags: angularjs

I am using  AngularJS v1.4.8

when i try to display that field with `ng-bing-html`, whole page content overwrite.

for example

```
<script>
document.write("hello");
</script>
```

url start infinite loading instead of `ng-bind-html` tag.

Comment: The write() method writes HTML expressions or JavaScript code to a document and it will delete all existing HTML.

Answer (score 0):

The write() method writes HTML expressions or JavaScript code to a document and it will delete all existing HTML.

The ng-bind-html directive is a secure way of binding content to an HTML element.

Refer to the ng-bind-html in following document.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

```
 <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
     <p ng-bind-html="myHTML"></p>
    </div>

     $scope.myHTML =
           'I am an <code>HTML</code>string with ' +
           '<a href="#">links!</a> and other <em>stuff</em>';
```